# how to write to a file safely in wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

I know about Reader Writer Lock Slim to write to a file in threadsafe manner(by using singleton pattern). But is it the right one to use while doing file operations using a wcf service?..will this work correctly in wcf service?

As I understand using the following :

[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]

will make the entire service instance as singleton. Where I don't want the other used type objects in my service to be singleton and only the type object which does the file operations to work as singleton for safe file operations, I cannot use the above thing as i understand.

Then what will be the best method to write to file safely across service calls?

Please correct if I have understood it wrongly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To which kind of file do you wanna write? To a log file?

Comment: No a file which will maintain some information for each call. I feel there is no difference with log file. similar but a separate file.

Comment: and service also reads out the file for some information

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about the contents to be written? Is it "just" a bit of meta data about each invocation?

Comment: yes sure. The service receives a request xml and decipher some details from it and validates based on the entries in the text file. And then does some update to the file. it happens for each call. Normal read write opreration to a text file/csv.

Comment: I have same question, anybody has answer? How thread safe log file in WCF web service?